# What does the `#[lang = "..."]` attribute do?

Tags: rust

I'm reading the code at https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.56.0/src/core/str/mod.rs.html#120-122:

```rust
#[lang = "str"]
#[cfg(not(test))]
impl str {
...
```

and I can't find a reference to this attribute `lang`. Does it have something to do with declaring the structure of the primitive type `str`? And if so, where is the information dealing with the inner structure of `str`?

Comment: Look up [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/5662)

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/lang-items.html

Answer (score 1):

`#[lang = "..."]` defines a [language item](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/lang-items.html), which allows the Rust compiler to look up the item it is attached to and potentially add special behavior.

In the case of `#[lang = "str"]`, the Rust compiler currently (as of October 2021) uses the `str` language item to collect methods defined on the `str` primitive so they can be looked up when called. The compiler also uses the `str` language item to prevent multiple inherent `impl`s (in this case, `impl str { ... }`) from being defined for the `str` primitive.