# Are all Rust attributes Macros?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

Are all attributes in Rust implemented as Macros? Or some native attributes are created specially by the compiler/language and does not use the Macros mechanism?

If there are attributes not created via Macros, how do I identify them?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69725428

Comment: Why do you want to identify them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many attributes that are not macros and are treated specifically by the compiler. Examples: [`#[cfg]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute) (although this one can be considered as a macro, even if not implemented as one), [`#[repr]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-layout.html#representations), [`#[doc]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/comments.html#doc-comments), [`#[allow(...)]`/`#[warn(...)]`/`#[deny(...)]`/`#[forbid(...)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/attributes/diagnostics.html#lint-check-attributes), and many more.

I don't know a way to identify such attributes except to look at [the list of builtin macro attributes](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/91f128baf7704a477ab7c499143a160fb069b3ad/compiler/rustc_builtin_macros/src/lib.rs#L93-L99) and see if they're there.

Comment: just not sure how the source code you pointed to show the list of builtin macro attributes, because from the look of things, it does not look like it

Comment: @FinlayWeber It is. This is the code in the compiler responsible to register them and their expander.